# Getting "Too many requests" error when scraping a particular website using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, python-requests

I have written a spider to fetch details from http://allevents.in.
Every time I tried to scrap, I am getting a response body

```
Too many requests, please try after some time or report this problem at contact@allevents.in
```

I tried using the shell command also.

```
 scrapy shell 'http://allevents.in/new%20delhi/all'
```

But still I am getting the same response for `response.body`.
I have tried other websites like [amazon](http://www.amazon.in) which works fine.
Also the above url can be fetched using `requests` as well as `urllib.urlopen()`.

Here is my `settings.py` file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Scrapy settings for tutorial project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
#
#     http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#     http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#     http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

BOT_NAME = 'tutorial'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['tutorial.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'tutorial.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'tutorial (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
# CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 5
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 1
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 1

# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
COOKIES_ENABLED = False

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
# TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Override the default request headers:
# DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
#   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
#   'Accept-Language': 'en',
# }

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
#SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'tutorial.middlewares.TutorialSpiderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
# DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
# #    'tutorial.middlewares.MyCustomDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
#      'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': None,
#      # 'tutorial.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 100,
# }

# Enable or disable extensions
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
#EXTENSIONS = {
#    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
#}

# Configure item pipelines
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
#ITEM_PIPELINES = {
#    'tutorial.pipelines.TutorialPipeline': 300,
#}

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

# Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
# HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
# HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
# HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
#HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
# HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'
```

I am a beginner in scrapy. please help

Comment: Basically they allevents must have tracked your scrapper and as a preventive measure they might have blocked ip address of your source system. There is nothing wrong at your end its allevents service which has disabled your spider. You can change your IP and check if it possible for you.

Comment: I have tried with a different ip. But still getting the same output @MaheshKaria

Comment: There are many more things are taken into considerations such as client type, requests etc so at this point we really don't know all criteria why they have blocked.

Answer (score 4):

Scrapy uses multiple concurrent requests (8 by default) to scrap the websites you specify. It seems that allevents.in doesn't like when you hit it too much.

Most likely, your solution will be to set one of the following config options:

- `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` (defaults to 8, try using a smaller number)
- `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP` (defaults to 0, overrides the previous one if set to a positive number)

---

Alternatively, you could also use the [AutoThrottle extension](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html).

Comment: How can I set that? I have tried using scrapy shell @yorah

Comment: You can pass command-line options to the scrapy shell with this syntax: scrapy shell -s CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN='8' http://...

Comment: Also, if you launch the scrapy shell from your project path, then your project settings should automatically be used.

Comment: I have tried with CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN=1 still the same error

Comment: Basically, the website is telling you: "dont hit me so hard". By setting `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN=1`, you are limiting the number of connection to 1. You can also try setting the option `DOWNLOAD_DELAY=5` to set a 5 seconds delay between those requests (feel free to increase/decrease this value to find the optimal one).

Comment: I understood what you are saying. I have done all those steps. But still I dont understand why it is not working. I have edited and attached my settings.py. kindly have a look

Answer (score 1):

Hi try assigning in the [`settings.py`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html) the `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1` and increase it gradually if you see it works, if that still receives the same warning try setting a higher `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`

Answer (score 0):

Use `scrapy-random-proxies` instead of applying auto throttle, there is no fun limiting the crawler when you can achieve goal at a higher speed - believe me, they will never know you where there if you use few hundreds proxies {more always better}.